# ASP.NET Custom CustomValidator and EnableClientScript

Tags: c#, asp.net, customvalidator, custom-validators

I have a custom validator (called CheckBoxListValidator) that inherits from CustomValidator that is designed to validate whether one or more checkboxes are selected from a CheckBoxList. Server-side validation functions exactly as expected, but the client-side validation never fires. I've tried something as simple as an alert in the function just to see if it will fire, but even that doesn't fire. Here is the full code of the control. As a note, I do see the script in the generated HTML so EnableClientScript has been set properly. It just doesn't fire.

```
public class CheckBoxListValidator : CustomValidator //BaseValidator
{        

    /// <summary>
    /// Ensures the control this validator is validating is the proper type.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>True if the control being validated is a CheckBoxList, otherwise false.</returns>
    protected override bool ControlPropertiesValid()
    {
        var ctrl = FindControl(this.ControlToValidate);
        return (ctrl != null && ctrl is CheckBoxList);
    }

    protected override bool OnServerValidate(string value)
    {
        return base.OnServerValidate(value);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Determines whether this control is in a valid state.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>True if one or more items has been selected, otherwise false.</returns>
    protected override bool EvaluateIsValid()
    {
        var clk = this.FindControl<CheckBoxList>(this.ControlToValidate);
        return clk.GetSelectedItems().Count > 0;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Attaches the client validation script to the 
    /// rendered page if ClientScript is enabled.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreRender(e);
        if (this.EnableClientScript)
            this.CreateClientScript();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates the client script to validate the control.
    /// </summary>
    private void CreateClientScript()
    {
        this.ClientValidationFunction = "validateCheckboxList";

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        var clk = this.FindControl<CheckBoxList>(this.ControlToValidate);            
        sb.AppendLine("function validateCheckboxList(sender, args) { alert('validateCheckboxList'); args.IsValid = false; }");

        Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "CheckBoxListValidator", sb.ToString(), true);
    }
}
```

Comment: You setting the ControlToValidate property correctly in the designer?

Comment: It's explicitly set in the control that uses this (a custom one that inherits from CheckBoxList). The validator fires server-side which tells me all of that is correct, it's just not firing the client side.